# NHibernate: Using a LINQ expression with IQueryOver

Tags: linq, nhibernate

I'm trying to use the IQueryOver interface of a NHibernate session object together with a LINQ expression as a criteria for selecting records in a static class. The LINQ expressions are defined in a mapping class as `Expression<Func<T, object>>` to get a value for an object T:

```
public void SearchParameter(Expression<Func<T, object>>)
```

These parameters get added by extending the mapping class:

```
public MyMapping : FindMap<MyNHibernateMappedObject>
{
    public MyMapping()
    {
        this.SearchParameter(x => x.SomeColumn);
    }
}
```

My Find class defines static methods for getting the previous and next record of the same type on the time axis. Each search parameter has to be identical in both records.

The Find class gets the search parameters from the mapping configuration and compiles the expressions with .Compile(). So I have the GetQueryWithSearchParameters method:

```
private static Func<T, object> searchParameter;

...

public static IQueryOver<T, T> GetQueryWithSearchParameters(ISession session, T current)
{
    var query = session.QueryOver<T>()
                       .Where(x => searchParameter(x) == searchParameter(current));
    return query;
}
```

However when building the query, I get the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: variable 'x' of type MyNHibernateMappedObject' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined
```

I don't know exactly what is going on here, but I suspect that x is not available in the delegate somehow. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

session.QueryOver().Where(...) takes an expression, so it's going to try evaluate your expression and translate it to a query - ie. it will try to convert searchParameter(x) == searchParameter(current) into a SQL query, which it won't know how to do.

To get this to work you will need to construct the expression in code (not using a lambda expression).  However I think that this is going to be a painful exercise and I think you will find it much easier to build a Criterion and add that to the QueryOver.